# Counting Bigrams in a Certain Category

Tags: python, categories

I am trying to create a function that counts the number of bigrams in a specific section of the Brown Corpus in NLTK. I created the function

```
def category_bigram_count(bigrams,category):
    category_text=nltk.corpus.brown.words(categories=category)
    return sum(1 for bg in category_text if bg==bigrams)
```

But obviously when I try to use this function like

```
category_bigram_count("The","Office","government")
```

I am giving 3 arguments, instead of the two I put in my function. How am I able to get this right? I think I have to change the function to take in 3 arguments, like "word1", "word2", "category" but I can't quite get it.

If I want to do it the long way I can do

```
govwords = nltk.corpus.brown.words(categories="government")
govbigrams = nltk.bigrams(govwords)
govbifreq = nltk.FreqDist(govbigrams)
govbifreq["The","Office"]
2
```

But is there a way to edit my function so that I don't have to do this for each category?

Comment: What's the purpose of this? You want to select all the bigrams in a specific category? How `word` and `word2` play a role?

Comment: The purpose of this is to be able to count bigrams in a specific category. For example I would like to know how many times "he said" appears in the category mystery. So I would like to have something that was like category_bigram_count("he", "said", "mystery"). And it would count it. For this example, word1 is he and word2 is said.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure I get what you want to do but if:

- you get all the words for a specific category
- you build the bigrams
- you calculate the frequencies per bigram
- you retrieve the frequency for the specific bigram

wouldn't you get what you need?

In code:

```
def category_bigram_count(word1, word2, category):
    words = nltk.corpus.brown.words(categories=category)
    bigrams = nltk.bigrams(words)
    freqbig = nltk.FreqDist(bigrams)
    return freqbig[(word1, word2)]
```

Comment: Your description is pretty accurate of what I am trying to do, which helps me think about it a different way. The code though, when ran, still says it is looking for 2 arguments, when category_bigram_count("the", "man", "learned) is 3.